# @Autowired inside @Entity not working properly

Tags: java, spring, autowired

When I log in to my applications I get a `NullPointerException` at an `@Autowired` field `hashProvider`. The strange thing is, it happens only sometimes! When I tried the debug mode, the field was autowired, when I run it normally, it was not.

```
@Configurable(preConstruction=true)
@Entity
@Table(name="DB_USER")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "USER_TYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class User extends AbstractEntity {

     //...

    @Autowired(required = true)
    private transient HashProvider hashProvider; 

     //...

    public boolean hasPassword(String password){
        LOG.info("is null "+(hashProvider==null));   //sometimes is null sometimes not
        return hashProvider.computeHash(password + salt).equals(this.password);  //null pointer
    }
}

@Component("hashProvider")
public class SHA1Provider implements HashProvider{
    //...
    @Override
    public String computeHash(String s) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Also logging as different users throws the exception or not. While logging in as `Doctor`, the field is null, as `AdminUser`, the field is not

```
@Entity
public class AdminUser extends User {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "AdminUser{" + '}';
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean isAdmin() {
        return true;
    }    
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("doctor")
public class Doctor extends User {

    private String address;

    @Column(length = 10, unique = true, name = "DOCTOR_BCN", nullable = false)
    private Long birthNumber;

    private Integer phone;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "doctor")
    @OrderBy("name ASC")
    private List<Patient> patients;

    //setters and getters       

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return super.toString() + "Doctor{}";
    }

    @Override
    public Boolean isAdmin() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the applicationContext.xml file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"
        >
    <!-- Use annotation to configure Spring context -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- Search for beans under the com.wpa package (Using annotation @Component, @Repository, @Service) -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.wpa"/>
    <!-- @Configurable support -->
    <context:spring-configured/>
    <!-- Property files -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="locations">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/properties/jdbc.properties</value>
                <value>/WEB-INF/properties/jpa.properties</value>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Connection pool -->
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource" destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- This defines the EntityManagerFactory bean, which provides the application with EntityManager instances = persistence context -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="${jpa.platform}"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
            </bean> 
        </property>
        <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>
                <entry key="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-or-extend-tables" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.wpa"/>
        <property name="jtaDataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Transaction manager for declarative transactional demarcation -->
    <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Use the declared transaction manager to manage transaction using the @Transactional annotation -->
    <!-- proxy-target-class=true enables use of concrete classes without interfaces as beans with the @Transactional annotation -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager" proxy-target-class="true" />
        <bean id="transactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
        <property name="transactionManager">
            <ref bean="txManager"/>
        </property>
    </bean>   
</beans>
```

Comment: Post the configuration file

Answer (score 0):

@Autowire can be used only on classes that was marked by spring. for example `@Service, @component ,@Repostitory`

EDIT: I missed the @Configurable which make this a spring ioc also.

Another thing i know is that if you write transient on member after deserialize it will be null.. Which seems to be very similar to your case.
Does that make sense?

EDIT:
Spring beans shouldn't be used in JPA entities.. This is bad practice.
The best practice to achieve this is the create wrapper that contain you pojo with additional functionality. I think the best thing is to leave logic in service even if it is a small logic..

Comment: Or on classes annotated with `@Configurable` when AOP is correctly configured (which in this case is, because sometimes it works).

Comment: I have the `@Configurable` annotation, since Entity is not managed by Spring, that should not be a problem.

Comment: Well I replaced  `private transient HashProvider hashProvider;` with `@Transient private HashProvider hashProvider;` and it worked. But I started it again and NullPointer. Then I cleared and built it and it's working. 
WHAT THE HELL.

Comment: Aviad, do you think it should not be transient? I don't think a helper object like this should be persisted.

Comment: I agree with you.. But this is not best practive to use spring bean inside a entity pojo.. This is why it doens't fit to your needs.. you have to change it and to make the logic of password in the service itself.. This will be the best practice. This is common problems in JPA, the pojo is only with his fields and cause a lot of issue..